# UIPopOverController issue

Tags: iphone, ipad

I am trying to display tableviewcontroller in a popover from a barbuttonitem like this :

```
- (IBAction)sortData:(id)sender {
    if(!sortViewController)
    sortViewController = [[SortDataViewController alloc] init];
    [sortViewController.tableView setDelegate:self];
    [sortViewController.tableView setTag:12];
    [sortViewController setIsMatter:YES];
    sortViewController.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(150, 100);
    sortViewController._radioSelection = 0;
    [sortViewController.tableView reloadData];
}

    if(!popOverController) {
        popOverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:sortViewController];
     }
    [popOverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(100, 100)];
    [popOverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
}
```

for the first time it got displayed for 1sec and automatically dismissed and from next time onwards it is not displaying at all. Can anyone please help me in this regard.

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with the code above. Can you post a bit more code (especially if you're dismissing it later on)?

Comment: This much is the code that I wrote till now, don't know what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am reloading the view after each second to test some requirement and forgot to disable it. So my view is reloading continuously and it's not giving enough time for popover to display it's view. Now I disabled it and the popover is working without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Set delegate for the UIPopOVerController...

```
    popOverController.delegate = self;
```